# onActivityResult returns null data for an video capture in Nexus 4 with v4.3

Tags: android, camera, video-capture

The onActivityResult returns null data for an video capture(Camcorder option). The functionality is working fine in all devices except the Nexus 4 device - v4.3 when we use the below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,  Constants.REQ_CODE_PICTURE_SNAP_RECORDER);
```

If we use the below code, the functionality is working fine in all devices except in the HTC One S v4.1.1 device.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
 currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,  Constants.REQ_CODE_PICTURE_SNAP_RECORDER);
```

The main problem is here the URI path is different like the below:

```
Getting File Location as:
    FileNotFoundException:
    /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ImagesFolder/VID_20140612_012146.3gp

Saving File Location is:
    mnt/sdcard/DCIM/ImagesFolder/VID_20140605_020203.3gp
```

Can you please anyone suggest me to fix this issue as generic for all mobile devices.